# Practice/learning "Junos OS" available? ( Junos OS/Juniper system )

Tags: juniper

I would like to learn Junos OS/Juniper by practicing on the system itself.
Is there such a resource on the internet? Possibly provided by Juniper for learning?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JUNOS/Olive](http://juniper.cluepon.net/index.php/Olive).

> Olive is also the codename name given to JUNOS software running on an PC rather than a Juniper router. A common misconception is that Olive is some sort of "special software", but it is actually ordinary JUNOS software running on a PC of similar specifications to a Routing Engine, with no forwarding hardware (or PFE) attached. If you took a Routing Engine out of a Juniper router and booted it in a blade server chassis, it would effectively be an Olive.
>   Juniper originally developed Olive functionality as a software development platform, before its hardware product was fully implemented. It is not intended as a "router simulator", and has never been a supported product, or intended for use by the general public in any way. At one point it was used by Juniper internally for lab work, but has largely been phased out of this role with the availability of low-end hardware based platforms such as the M5.
>   The most common use of the Olive platform is for creative and unix-competent hackers to learn the JUNOS CLI on a low-cost platform. It is capable of forwarding a small amount of traffic, but does not support many of the features found on real Juniper routers. Essentially the forwarding on an Olive is the same as routing traffic via your fxp0 or em0 management interface on a real Routing Engine.

Comment: Hi Fox, I think you "nailed it". I will try to install this on top of VMWare and learn the Junos cli